# Why pdf/svg in Xcode assets increases final ipa's size unnecessarily?

Tags: xcode, pdf, svg, vector, assets

## Reproduce

With Xcode 14.1, following steps can reproduce the phenomenon:

1. add a pdf file to the assets, and in attributes inspector, select "Preserve Vector Data", set "Scales" as "Single Scale".

[image: Screenshot: Xcode Assets - pdf file with "Preserve Vector Data" selected]

2. run Xcode->Product->Archive
3. follow the instruction of [create the app size report](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reducing-your-app-s-size) from apple official site. In the archives list, select "Distribute App" -> Ad Hoc ->App Thinning: **All compatible device variants** -> Next -> Automatically menage signing -> Next -> Export.
4. Now we check the exported folder, in the sub folder named "Apps", we can get 3 ipas.

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 xxxx  staff   386048 Nov 10 21:01 111002-582C7144-401C-4F99-8FA7-3B164292726E.ipa
-rw-r--r--@ 1 xxxx  staff   639517 Nov 10 21:01 111002-5A4FE73D-2DCB-4079-BB68-59FA54D31921.ipa
-rw-r--r--  1 xxxx  staff  1190004 Nov 10 21:01 111002.ipa
```

choose one specific ipa (**NOT** the universal one *111002.ipa*), we can choose one base on file "App Thinning Size Report.txt", unzip that ipa, enter the app folder, now we can find the file which name is "Assets.car".

5. we run the script "`xcrun --sdk iphoneos assetutil --info Assets.car`", then we get a output message, part of it like this:

```
{
    "AssetType" : "Image",
    "BitsPerComponent" : 8,
    "ColorModel" : "RGB",
    "Colorspace" : "srgb",
    "Compression" : "deepmap-lzfse",
    "Encoding" : "ARGB",
    "Idiom" : "universal",
    "Name" : "pdf",
    "NameIdentifier" : 19593,
    "Opaque" : false,
    "PixelHeight" : 842,
    "PixelWidth" : 595,
    "Preserved Vector Representation" : true,
    "RenditionName" : "pdf.pdf",
    "Scale" : 1,
    "SHA1Digest" : "5C71A688035EDA13684D904E6F272BC9B0F7ABF8D5AFE1C44915FDC99AB5DC4E",
    "SizeOnDisk" : 71134,
    "State" : "Normal",
    "Template Mode" : "automatic",
    "Value" : "Off"
  },
  {
    "AssetType" : "Image",
    "BitsPerComponent" : 8,
    "ColorModel" : "RGB",
    "Colorspace" : "srgb",
    "Compression" : "deepmap-lzfse",
    "Encoding" : "ARGB",
    "Idiom" : "universal",
    "Name" : "pdf",
    "NameIdentifier" : 19593,
    "Opaque" : false,
    "PixelHeight" : 2526,
    "PixelWidth" : 1785,
    "Preserved Vector Representation" : true,
    "RenditionName" : "pdf.pdf",
    "Scale" : 3,
    "SHA1Digest" : "BB0E06CEB24DBF6A89D38BAFCBAE5D6322CED922FDD30E4A5E4A22C9079B7390",
    "SizeOnDisk" : 369765,
    "State" : "Normal",
    "Template Mode" : "automatic",
    "Value" : "Off"
  },
  {
    "AssetType" : "Vector",
    "Colorspace" : "generic",
    "Height" : 842,
    "Idiom" : "universal",
    "Name" : "pdf",
    "NameIdentifier" : 19593,
    "RenditionName" : "pdf.pdf",
    "Scale" : 1,
    "SHA1Digest" : "03F9900F23A26D421A8A612372849CCFB2952E7C47D99DA514B770AE1908C283",
    "SizeOnDisk" : 43409,
    "State" : "Normal",
    "Value" : "Off",
    "Width" : 595
  }
```

This means there are 3 files in the Assets.car. And we can use some tools to export them out. e.g [QLCARFiles](https://github.com/Timac/QLCARFiles) and we can get these 3 files.

```
-rw-r--r--   1 xxxxx  staff   43185 Nov 10 21:20 pdf.pdf
-rw-r--r--   1 xxxxx  staff  113023 Nov 10 21:20 pdf-UIAppearanceAny.png
-rw-r--r--   1 xxxxx  staff  343966 Nov 10 21:20 pdf-UIAppearanceAny@2x.png
```

## My question is

as I already selected "**Preserve Vector Data**" in Xcode, why my device still get two unnecessary png files?

In my opinion, what my device need is only that pdf.pdf file, do not need these two png file.(pdf-UIAppearanceAny.png / pdf-UIAppearanceAny.png), **these have no benefit except increased unnecessary ipa's size.**

I also used svg file and can got same phenomenon, I googled a lot, no useful message found.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I found the same, and this impacts the .ipa size significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the minimum iOS version for your app is <= iOS 12?

The "vector data preservation" + SVG support is only available on macOS 10.15 or later, iOS 13 or later, and iPadOS 13 or later.
Else Xcode will fallback to generating png files when building an app archive.

The following blogs explain it a lot better than i can, have read.

- https://sarunw.com/posts/svg-image-assets-supported-in-xcode12/
- https://www.avanderlee.com/xcode/svg-image-assets/
- https://www.willowtreeapps.com/craft/what-svg-support-means-for-your-ios-app-graphics